# Cant remove ',' from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing some code that is supposed to output the values of two inputted lists, sort them, and display them.
I can get it to return the values, but it is also returning a bunch of commas. I browsed StackOverflow and Reddit to find different methods, but can't find one that works. Can someone take a look at my code and see what I am doing wrong here?

```
if response == 'Combine':
    def combo():
        list1 = [numblist1]
        list2 = [numblist2]
        numblist1 = input('Enter your first list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- ')
        numblist2 = input('Enter your second list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- ')
        list3 = [list1+list2]
        numblist4 = map(float, 'list3'.split(','))
        return(sorted(numblist4))
```

also for some reason the code will output this when I run it:

```
What would you like to do: Sift, Check, Sum, Reverse or Combine?Combine
Enter your first list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- 1,4,3
Enter your second list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- 4,6,5
(1, 4, 3) <---I have no idea why this is being displayed
[1, 3, 4] <---I have no idea why this is being displayed
[',', ',', ',', ',', '1', '3', '4', '4', '5', '6']
```

Here is everything...

```
print('-----------------------------------------------')
print()
print('Below is a short dictonary of this programs functions:')
print('Sift - Takes list and reduces all  duplicated elements to single values.')
print('Check - Identifies wether or not the values are in the correct order.')
print('Sum - Adds values from list together and returns the sum of those values.')
print('Reverse - Returns elements from list in reversed order')
print('Combine - Combines elements from two list and returns them in single sorted list')
print()
response = input('What would you like to do: Sift, Check, Sum, Reverse or Combine?')

if response == 'Combine':
    def combo():
        list1 = [numblist1]
        list2 = [numblist2]
        numblist1 = input('Enter your first list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- ')
        numblist2 = input('Enter your second list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- ')
        list3 = [list1+list2]
        numblist4 = map(float, 'list3'.split(','))
        return(sorted(numblist4))

if response == 'Sum':
    def add():


numblist1 = input('Enter your first list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- ')
numblist2 = input('Enter your second list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- ')
numblist3 = numblist1+numblist2
numblist1 = eval(numblist1)


print(numblist1)
print(sorted(numblist1))
print(sorted(numblist3)
```

Comment: `numblist1 = [float(i) for i in numblist1.split(',')]` (same for `listnumb2`) and `numblist4 = numblist1 + numblist2`. That should do the trick

Comment: You should explain how it's not working. That said, I see some obvious errors; you're using `numblist1` and `numblist2` before you get them from the user, you have more lists than you need, and you're trying to split the string `'list3'` instead of the input string. And others. Are you sure this code does anything? It looks like it has multiple errors that would prevent it from even running, let alone giving you the values plus some commas.

Comment: Also, why are you defining a function in an if block? Perhaps you could show us your entire script?

Comment: @Cyphase Thanks for replying. I am just barely learning python so please bare with me ok :(. Yes it does something, the second piece of my question outlines another problem I am having where it displays list1 and then displays a sorted version of list1 AND THEN does what its supposed to do which is combine list1 and list2 to create list3, numblist4 is then used to split the commas from list3 so it can be output. I am updating the og post with my full code although you guys will probably find it rediculous.

Comment: You're trying to split the string `'list3'`. That's two mistakes in one: using a string instead of the variable's actual name, and trying to use `split()` on what you think is a `list`. You really should look into the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) or you will have a very tough time figuring it out as you go along.

Comment: I still don't see the whole code...

Comment: @Brambor I have just updated it.

Comment: @noerror, your code does not run. Even if it did, it's got major flaws. I don't mean to discourage you, but perhaps you need to review some fundamentals :).

Comment: You have an `if` statement which does nothing but define a function, never call it, and throw it away. It refers to strings that are only assigned after the `if` block. You're using `eval()`. You're trying to `split()` the _name_ of a `list`.

Comment: @Cyphase: it's a quantum function in an existential crisis. At any given time it can be thought to both exist and not exist; but until you check the value of `response`, you can't know for sure

Comment: I have nothing to do so I might rewrite your program to working state, but be sure to read some turtorials and then parts of documentation of things you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I have something and I'm not sure if that is what you wanted, but here it is:

```
print('-----------------------------------------------')
print()
print('Below is a short dictonary of this programs functions:')
print('Sift - Takes list and reduces all  duplicated elements to single values.')
print('Check - Identifies wether or not the values are in the correct order.')
print('Sum - Adds values from list together and returns the sum of those values.')
print('Reverse - Returns elements from list in reversed order')
print('Combine - Combines elements from two list and returns them in single sorted list')
print()
response = input('What would you like to do: Sift, Check, Sum, Reverse or Combine?')

#if response == 'Sum':
#    def add():
#       pass

list1 = input('Enter your first list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- ')
list2 = input('Enter your second list in the following format: [X,X,X,X] ---- ')

list1, list2 = list1.split(","), list2.split(",")
if response == 'Combine':
    list3 = list1 + list2
    list3 = sorted(list3)

input(list3) # same as print(list3); input()
```

I didn't do any upgrades, if you want it to be function, then ask me but it is easy... You were doing there some crazy stuff and maybe I missed some functions that you want your program to do, if yes, then ask me for them :)